# XLPaste Code applying differently to separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a question about this piece of code yesterday but this is part two. Once the identified sheets have detached from the original workbook, they maintain all of their formulas (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats). There are two sheets in particular, "REQUESTOR" and "Copy", that am only needing the values for but the other 3 sheets need to bring their formulas along during the detachment. The reason is because those 2 sheets contain external referencing formulas while the other 3 do not. How do I get all of the sheets to detach into a new work book and make the 2 identified sheets be values only while the other 3 carry all of their formulas into the new workbook?

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



 ' Plain_Copy Macro

Sheets("PROCUREMENT").Visible = True
Sheets("Request").Visible = True
Sheets("LISTS").Visible = True
Sheets("Copy").Visible = True

Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
Dim TempWindow As Window
Dim ws As Worksheet
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets(Array("REQUESTOR", "PROCUREMENT", "Request", "LISTS", "Copy")).Copy

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
     TempWindow.Close
Next ws




Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: After `PasteSpecial` add line `If ws.Name = "REQUESTOR" Or ws.Name = "Copy" Then .Value2 = .Value2`

Comment: Looks like that didnt work, its still pasting the formulas in the cells

Comment: I took out the xlPastevaluesandnumberformats and put your code under the .pastespecial

Comment: I get an error with this line `TempWindow.Close`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any potential problems with nesting `With ActiveWorkbook` for both the original and the copy by assigning them to variables and then it is clear which is being processed.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  
     ' Plain_Copy Macro
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar, v
    ar = Array("REQUESTOR", "PROCUREMENT", "Request", "LISTS", "Copy")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        For Each v In ar
            .Sheets(v).Visible = True
        Next
        .Sheets(ar).Copy
        Set wbCopy = ActiveWorkbook
    End With
   
    For Each ws In wbCopy.Worksheets
        If ws.name = "REQUESTOR" Or ws.name = "Copy" Then
            With ws.UsedRange
               ' replace formula with values
               .Value2 = .Value2
            End With
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Copy is " & wbCopy.name 
End Sub
```

Comment: Pasted the code into the vba and it is still carrying over the formulas and not reverting those selected pages into value only.

Comment: I've tried a few other long written out methods and it seems to default to whichever code comes first, meaning all sheets are either value or formula.. Starting to feel like this wont work out..

Comment: @Ted How are you running the code , from a button or the VBA editor ? Do you get the message box ?

Comment: The code is triggered once a button gets clicked. I do not get a message box once the new workbook pops up

Comment: @Run the code from the editor. If you don't get a message box with "Copy is" then your button can't be running the right code.

Comment: Just ran it through the Editor and it did the same thing without the message box. I also went into design mode, clicked on the button, and selected view code. It brought me to the same code that you gave me so that tells me that its referencing the right piece of code when its clicked.

Comment: Now, I don't know if this matters, but when I double click on the Sheet7 or "REQUESTOR" excel object inside of the editor, it opens up the Module that contains this piece of code for the button. I was under the impression that these types of codes should live in their own space as private subs and not directly tied to that sheet, but only to that button. I could be totally wrong but that's the only thing that I see is out of place.

Comment: @Ted Add a break point to the line `ar = Array..` . Press the button and single step with F8 through the program to the End Sub to check all the lines are being executed. Are you running this on a windows desktop, not a Mac or via a VPN ?

Comment: Im using a windows laptop at work.. So i added the breakpoint on that line and toggled through. It fails right after the `For Each v In ar
            .Sheets(v).Visible = True` right before the "next" code. Error is "9" subscript out of range

Comment: not to question your coding, but did we have to identify what the "v" is since we identified what the "ar" is? @CDP1802

Comment: @ted that error is because one of the sheets in the array doesn't exist or it has hidden spaces in the name

Comment: I honestly have never heard of hidden spaces before. I went back through and retyped the names of the sheets and it let me toggle through it. I ran a test and it looks like you've solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ted Worksheet names can have spaces at the beginning or end that you can't see until you try to rename them. I don't know why the error did not appear when you ran the code unless you have `On Error Resume Next` lurking in the code somewhere.

Comment: Ill send you a chunk of this bonus ill be getting for completing this final step of my project boss! lol, thanks again